# Seeking a record with Dracula, the Wolfman, and Frankenstein

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I don't know where to look to find information (and hopefully copies) of old children's records.  I had a lot of them ([I've asked before about some of the oldest ones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165507/looking-for-78-rpm-childrens-records-with-fairy-tales-and-classical-music)), and there are a few that I would particularly like to get access to again.

One in particular that came back to me today was a story about "Dracula, the Wolfman, and Frankenstein," with all three names on the front cover.  Inside the album was a comic book to read along with the story, illustrating it.  (I had a few records with these kinds of comic book insets, and I loved them.)  The story involves Victor Frankenstein's nephew being lured into Dracula's castle and convinced to create a new animated monster to serve the vampire.  In the midst of this, apparently as a bargaining chip, Dracula gets the younger Frankenstein's fiance Erica turned into a werewolf and thrown in with a band of gypsies, ruled by a female werewolf.

As each of the monsters was introduced, it had the monster's name taking up about a third of the whole page in the comic book insert.  The order was Frankenstein first, then the Wolfman, then Dracula, whose identity is not revealed until the end of the story.  (However, my father said that the actor voicing Dracula made it quite obvious, since he was imitating Bela Lugosi's voice.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely *[A Story of Dracula, The Wolfman, and Frankenstein](https://www.horrorsociety.com/2014/06/06/comic-crypt-power-records-monsters/)*

[image: Record cover]

> It tells the story of Baron Frankenstein’s nephew Vincent and his girlfriend as they are helped by a kindly, aristocratic man who offers them refuge in his castle.  Well, he turns out to be Dracula of course, and he wants Frankie’s nephew to create a monster for him that will obey and watch over the Count while he sleeps during the day.  Dracula threatens to kill Victor’s girlfriend so he will make him a monster.  The monster comes to life and throws Victor’s girlfriend out the castle window and she is attacked by a werewolf, thus turning her into one as well.  The action concludes as all 3 monsters clash in the story’s finale.  As a child of 8, this was the ultimate monster book-and-record set due to the fact it had all of the “big 3” monsters all in one story.  The artwork was fantastic and the record story was terribly exciting and scary all at the same time.

A further review, and a few of the comic book pages, can be found [here](https://diggingforderelicts.com/blog/a-story-of-dracula-the-wolfman-and-frankenstein-1975)

Found by searching for `record "frankenstein's nephew"`

Comment: I don't see the connection.

Comment: That's it, of course.  However, based on the lengths of the videos, it seems like that story would have only occupied one side of a LP record.  I wonder why.